# Does Ubuntu  support 8Gb of RAM?

Tags: 64-bit, hardware, ram

I've a motherboard that can accept 8G RAM, But Window only see and use 4G RAM. If I put in my 8G RAM sticks, Will installing a 64bit version of Ubuntu really access most of the 8G's, Or is this a pipe dream?

System Specs:

```
Intel core 2 Q6600 quad
Intel motherboard DG965WH
4G ram (currently installed)
1TB (2 disks)
Vista x64
ATI Radeon HD5670
```

Comment: If you already have the 8G sticks, put them in and try a Ubuntu live CD to see if they are recognized...  They should be...

Answer (score 4):

You can run more than 4gb on a 32 bit system with [PAE, or physical address extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) - which i believe the default 32 bit kernel comes with, but 64 bit would have better performance, and the system itself supports [4x 2gb sticks for 8 gigs](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/dg965wh/sb/CS-026599.htm). There's no reason why it should not work

Answer (score 2):

Yes; Ubuntu supports more than 4GB of ram, even on the 32bit version.  Microsoft has decided you have to pay extra for a build of windows ( server edition ) that supports more than 4gb of ram on 32 bit, though IIRC, Vista 64 bit should also support 8gb of ram.

Comment: Good answer, but I'm confident this has already been asked somewhere

Comment: `Microsoft has decided you have to pay extra for a build of windows that supports more than 4gb of windows on 32 bit` -> no, this is incorrect. PAE doesn't require another "build" or that you pay extra. Where did you hear this?

Comment: @sathya http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension "Microsoft Windows implements PAE if booted with the appropriate option, but current 32-bit desktop editions enforce the physical address space within 4GB even in PAE mode. According to Geoff Chappell, Microsoft limits 32-bit versions of Windows to 4GB as a matter of its licensing policy," SOURCE: http://www.geoffchappell.com/notes/windows/license/memory.htm

Comment: @psusi To me your answer is corect and the downvote should not have been given. So upvoted ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind be that as may be, you don't have to pay extra for the 64-bit version. You're licensed to use 64-bit & 32-bit with the same key, albeit not simultaneously. The DV still holds because this *is* incorrect --> `Microsoft has decided you have to pay extra for a build of windows that supports more than 4gb of windows on 32 bit`. No you *don't* have to. Grab the 64-bit edition.

Comment: @sathya He says "you have to pay extra fpr more than 4Gb on a 32 bit system". That stmt is correct.

Comment: @Rinzwind There is no "pay extra for 4Gb" option. If I am wrong, please cite me a source where I can *puchase* such an option. Thank you.

Comment: @Sathya, he already did.  The more expensive server edition of windows can use the full 64 gb of pae addressable memory, which is what I was referring to.

Comment: @Sathya: So why did we (as in the organisation I was with, way back in the old days) "need" to purchase the 64 bit version again, when we already had the 32 bit?

Comment: #sathya HOME editions that are sold all over the world do NOT accept PAE. PRO editions do accept PAE but you -must- buy that as a new license.